# UIScrollView Height Not Working After Showing Modal

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, mwphotobrowser

I'm retrieving json data from server. The json data includes some images and more text and last but not least json size is not **predictable**.

Here is how I retrieve json:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    if (self.jsonUrl == nil) { 
    // This control is about MWPhotoBrowser. If user returned from photo browser do not retrieve data twice

        self.view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.75f;
        self.view.layer.shadowRadius = 10.0f;
        self.view.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;

        if (![self.slidingViewController.underRightViewController isKindOfClass:[DetailContextViewController class]]) {
            self.slidingViewController.underRightViewController  = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailAbout"];
        }

        self.jsonUrl = [self.exampleAd getAdJSONLink];
        NSLog(@"%@", self.jsonUrl); // 

        [self backgroundTask]; // retrieving data
    } else {
        // User returned from MWPhotoBrowser so set the current height again/
        // This is not working somehow.
        [self.scrollView setContentSize:(CGSizeMake(320, currentHeight + 10))];
    }
}
```

I'm adding all those data to an `UIScrollView` as a subview. Let's say this is B view. So height of scrollview is uncertain. I'm calculating the height and setting like this:

```
[self.scrollView setContentSize:(CGSizeMake(320, currentHeight + 10))];
```

That's working well. Here is my problems: If I go back to A from B and again go A to B, content size is not working. Scrolling not working too, but my `currentHeight` is showing the right value. Even the retrieving method is not working enough, actually there is something like cache.

There is same problem while using `MWPhotoBrowser`. When I use present modal controller than return to B view again scroll is not working.

What am I doing wrong, any approach or clue would be great.